# MySQL selecting last row from group by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the most recent row from every group in a select, but with a little twist in it.

Get the following table for example:

```
 id , user_id , created_at          , balance 
 1  , 1       , 2016-01-01 01:01:01 , 1       
 2  , 1       , 2016-01-01 01:01:01 , 2
```

You can see that the `created_at` value is the same for the same user, and the problem is that I can't rely on the id field neither because nothing guarantees that the biggest id will be the last one.

If the created_at field wouldn't be duplicated the following query would work properly:

```
SELECT L.id
    , L.user_id
    , L.created_at
    , L.balance
FROM   log AS L
      JOIN
         (SELECT user_id
              , MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
          FROM   log
          GROUP BY user_id) MAX_TIME ON L.user_id = MAX_TIME.user_id
                                  AND L.created_at = MAX_TIME.max_created_at;
```

But because of the duplicated created_at, it will return two rows. 
So I can't rely only on the created_at field, but I'm confident that getting the max id if the created_at is duplication would give me the result I want.

So I need to add the id row as well somehow to this "group" mechanism. 
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it really doesn't matter which row you select you could just order by the unique row id and only select the top 1. And if you want the *last* row, i.e., the row with the greatest unique id, you'd want to `ORDER BY ... DESC`

```
SELECT TOP 1
      L.id
    , L.user_id
    , L.created_at
    , L.balance
FROM   log AS L
      JOIN
         (SELECT user_id
              , MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
          FROM   log
          GROUP BY user_id) MAX_TIME ON L.user_id = MAX_TIME.user_id
                                  AND L.created_at = MAX_TIME.max_created_at;
                                  ORDER BY L.id DESC
```

Comment: He said:
> and the problem is that I can't rely on the id field neither because nothing guarantees that the biggest id will be the last one. ...

Comment: I'm still maxing by created_at. I'm just narrowing the duplicate results by insignificantly picking a single id using ORDER BY.

Comment: The problem with this query is that it will return one row exactly. What is need is to return the most recent row of every user.

Comment: @emul You're problem is you haven't defined what "most recent" means outside of the `created_at` field. In the case with your data above, both fields are the "most recent" so returning them both (or just one) would be correct. If you don't have another way to identify what the most recent row is with the data you have then identifying the most *recenter* is impossible.

Comment: @LCIII As I wrote, if there are duplicates in the created_at field, I'd consider the bigger the row with the bigger id as the most recent one. I'm not saying that it would be a perfect solution but I guess that would be a close one

Comment: @emul That's exactly what my script is doing ↑. It's grouping the records by created_at then it's selecting the row with the bigger id.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your table with your ID as auto_increment (and I highly recommend this way) , The biggest one should be the newest row...

So:

```
SELECT L.id
    , L.user_id
    , L.created_at
    , L.balance
FROM   log AS L
      JOIN
         (SELECT user_id
              , MAX(id) AS last
          FROM   log
          GROUP BY user_id) MAX_TIME ON L.user_id = MAX_TIME.user_id
                                  AND L.id = MAX_TIME.last;
```

(just replace `created_at`  with `id`

But if you don't have "normal" ID, I think there is no way to do that...

Comment: The problem is as I wrote is that I can't rely on the auto_increment field. The reason is that this is a log table and the entries are not necessarily coming in order.

Comment: @emul OK, but in this case, you can't "really" select the latest (yes, it works based on date, but when dates are the same?)... For that, you need an absolute identifier that you can rely to a register order... So I have no other suggestions than create a second `id` field, filled by an `auto_increment`... otherwise your database system will not log the entry order... (for MySQL, maybe in information_schema, but I'm not sure, and it isn't a good way for retrieving data...). Or you can tell that this situation (same creation time!) is exceptional and won"t happen in production...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you actually need that self join?

Wouldn't

```
SELECT L.id
, L.user_id
, L.created_at
, L.balance
FROM log AS L
GROUP BY L.user_id
ORDER BY L.created_at DESC, L.id DESC;
```

get you the expected row?

Explanation: ordering happens first, that way the latest datetimes are already in the first rows. Because of the possibility of duplicate datetime values, we add another ordering by id. Now the row with the latest datetime and highest id will be in first row and then the results are grouped by user id.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an error because all the non user_id fields need to be aggregated too?

Comment: No, why should they be aggregated? Aggregation on non-grouped fields only happens with group functions, e.g. SUM(), AVG(), ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect this query would return. If you are using group by you have to either list the fields in the group by statement or aggregate somehow.